# How to typeset 'tis or 'em with TeX

Tags: typography, punctuation

Sometimes 'Tis will be used to represent "this is" and 'em will be used as "them" in spoken English, but how do I typeset them with TeX? Should the tick mark be "left quote" or "right quote" or some other symbol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that 'tis usually means "it is", but no matter.  Typeset them as you did here, with apostrophes (single right quotes).

Comment: Sounds right to me.  Apostrophes can be used to represent elided letters, as in *mustn’t* and other contractions.  This is the same thing with nothing on the left-hand side of the contraction.